# Bootstrap table checking

Tags: bootstrap-table

I was trying to check a row inside a Bootstrap table using this function:

```
$('#editMappingTable').bootstrapTable('check', var);
```

`var` is dynamic variable(number) which will have the row id I want to check but its not working.

If I use this technique :

```
$('#editMappingTable').bootstrapTable('check', 1);
```

the above one works well .

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are passing a valid row index